# Getting the value of the selected item from list box

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm currently practicing winforms using Visual Studio. I have this part of the code where if the user selects a region such as "Hokkaido". The combo box for the prefecture would only show the prefecture "Hokkaido" shown in the code below:

```
private void PopulatePrefecture()
        {
            if (listBox1.SelectedItem.Equals("Hokkaido"))
            {
                prefectureBox.Items.Add("Hokkaido");

            }

            else if (listBox1.SelectedItem.Equals("Tohoku"))
            {

                prefectureBox.Items.Add("Aomori");
                prefectureBox.Items.Add("Iwate");
                prefectureBox.Items.Add("Miyagi");
                prefectureBox.Items.Add("Akita");
                prefectureBox.Items.Add("Yamagata");
                prefectureBox.Items.Add("Fukushima");
            }
```

I have already called PopulatePrefecture in the Form Load. However, the combo box only shows blank.

Comment: to do this you have to fill the listBox on the selection so an event is needed.
`private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e) {`

Comment: I believe based on how your application is set up you need to use the `listBox1` event handler so something like `private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)` and then in that event just call your `PopulatePrefecture()` function.